# TableView Data Cells JSON

Tags: json, swift, parsing, tableview

I'm making an app that parses JSON data & populates a tableview. However, no matter what I try I can't retrieve the data correctly. It's all there, but I can't print it into the cells correctly. I have the following code set up for the JSON:

//JSON

```
    let url = NSURL(string:"https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/7flcy3qm?apikey=gNq3hB1j0NtBdAvXJLEFx8JaqtDG8y6Y")!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            if data != nil {
                // Create JSON object from data
                let json = JSON(data: data!)

                // Check if array for key "collection2" exists
                if let collection2 = json["results"]["collection2"].array {
                    // Create JSON array from it and loop for each object

                    for (_, subJson):(String, JSON) in JSON(collection2) {
                        // Check if dictionary for key "Event" exists

                        var data: [String: Any] = [String: Any]()

                        if let event = subJson["Event"].dictionary {
                            print(event)

                        }

                        // Check if string for key "Hasta" exists
                        if let text = subJson["Event"]["text"].string {
                            data["text"] = text
                            self.TableData.append(text)
                            print(text)
                        }

                        // Check if string for key "Hasta" exists
                        if let hasta = subJson["Hasta"].string {
                            data["hasta"] = hasta
                            self.TableData.append(hasta)
                            print(hasta)
                        }

                        // Check if string for key "Location" exists
                        if let location = subJson["Location"].string {
                            data["location"] = location
                            self.TableData.append(location)
                            print(location)
                        }

                        self.TableData.append(data)


                    }

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

}

My problem arises when I try to print the information in the cells, right now I get the first index row repeated. But, I'd like all the other rows there too. Here's what I've tried so far, and get problems about "converting strings", I've commented out some options that didn't get the result I wanted.
override func tableView(tableView: `UITableView`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath`) -> `UITableViewCell` {

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MasterTableViewCell

    let data = self.TableData[indexPath.row]


    //cell.textLabel1?.text = data["hasta"]
    //cell.textLabel1?.text = self.TableData[3]

    cell.textLabel?.text = data[hasta]

    //cell.textLabel2?.text = self.TableData[4]
    //cell.textLabel3?.text = self.TableData[2]

    return cell

}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks a lot everyone! :)

Comment: append data to self.TableData at the end of every  loop during parsing json  like this...           data["text"]= text      data["hasta"]= hasta self.TableData.append(data)

Comment: The closure is asynchronous, dispatch to main thread before you append and reload

Comment: I don't understand the dispatch to main thread part, sorry. Thanks guys!... I already have the "data["text"] = text etc, code, good4pc :) But, I get an error "cannot convert value of type [String: Any] to expected argument type 'String'"? And with this line "cell.textLabel?.text = data["hasta"]", I get this error: "cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String'"? Any thoughts?

Comment: Anyone care to help me out, please?

Comment: Do you have the solution? Showing not found https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/7flcy3qm?apikey=gNq3hB1j0NtBdAvXJLEFx8JaqtDG8y6Y